# phpunit selenium automated tests

Tags: javascript, selenium, phpunit

I am setting up automated tests to run on a website to ensure everything still works correctly.  I have a webpage displaying a table of records.

1. I want to test loading up a chosen webpage.
2. Select a checkbox for a chosen record
3. Select the 'Process Selected' button
4. Enter some dummy text in the textarea
5. Click Confirm to save the record

I have the first 3 steps completed, but I am stuck on step 4.  Can anyone help out please?
Thanks
Conor

```
<?php
    class AdminUserProcessSelectedNote extends PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase{
        public function setUp()
        {
            $this->setHost('localhost'); // Set the hostname for the connection to the Selenium server.
            $this->setPort(4444); // set port # for connection to selenium server
            $this->setBrowser('firefox'); // set the browser to be used
            $this->setBrowserUrl('http://www.myhost.com/');  // set base URL for tests
        }

        public function testAdminUserProcessSelectedNoteSelectReq3()
        {            
            $this->url('index.php'); // Set the URL to access the page
        // Select the specific checkbox with the Id
            $viewReqsCheckbox = $this->byId('jqg_requestGrid_request_4506');
        $viewReqsCheckbox ->click();

        // Now, Select the Process Selected button
            $processSelectedBtn = $this -> byId('processStateChangeButton');
        $processSelectedBtn ->click();

        // Make a note and Confirm
        $this->byName('dlg-stateChange-notes');        
        $this->setField('dlg-stateChange-notes','TEST NOTE');  
        $this->click('Confirm');  
    }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is: There is no method called `setField`.  Change...

```
$this->setField('dlg-stateChange-notes','TEST NOTE');
```

to

```
$this->sendKeys('dlg-stateChange-notes','TEST NOTE');
```

If that doesn't work, try using

```
$this->type('dlg-stateChange-notes','TEST NOTE');
```

Answer (score 0):

// byId,byClassName,byXpath you can set value.

```
 $this->byId('dlg-stateChange-notes')->value('TEST NOTE');
```